# Enviar e-mail para 1 array de contato, com phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Galera utilizo o php mailer para enviar e-mail, e muito simples, uso a seguinte linha:

```
// Destinatório e cópia oculta
$email->AddBCC('hugoborges@gmail.com', 'hugo');
```

Porém queria saber como faço para enviar um e-mail para várias pessoas em um array?

Alguém poderia me dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$recipients = array(
   'person1@domain.com' => 'Person One',
   'person2@domain.com' => 'Person Two',
   // ..
);
foreach($recipients as $email => $name)
{
   $mail->AddBCC($email, $name);
}
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149452/php-mailer-multiple-address)

Comment: hum ok vlw. vou testar aqui

Comment: esta dando erro dessa forma: Fatal error: Call to a member function AddBCC() on string in

Comment: Conseguiu encontrar o erro @HugoBorges ?

Comment: sim sim, eu tenho colocado uma variável com o nome errado :), obrigado

Comment: Ah então blz. Só tinha visto o comentário agora haha.

Comment: hahah tranquilo. estou tendo dificuldade de como montar o array usando o while tem como me ajudar?

Comment: Claro, pode postar outra pergunta. Ou me add no skype.

Comment: vlw, segue o link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141988/montando-um-array-com-php-para-p-phpmailer