# montando um array com php para p phpmailer

Tags: php, array

Galera estou tentando montar um array com a lista de endereços de e-mail, para que o phpmailer os enviem. Porém estou tendo problemas.

Não e exibido erro algum, o php simplesmente não enviar os e-mails.

Estou montando o array assim:

```
     // Define os destinatário(s)
        $consulta = $mysqli->query("select email,nome from clientes where status=true");
        while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta)) {

            // Monta o array
            $destinatario[] = array($resultado->email => $resultado->nome);
        }
```

E envio assim:

```
foreach($destinatario as $email_cliente => $name){
    $mail->AddBCC($email_cliente, $name);
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar? Acho que o problema esta na montagem do array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente fazer dessa forma Hugo:

```
    // Define os destinatário(s)
    $consulta = $mysqli->query("select email, nome from clientes where status=true");

    while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta)) {
        // Monta o array
        $destinatario[] = $resultado;
    }

    foreach($destinatario as $key => $value){
        $mail->AddBCC($value->email, $value->name);
    }
```

Comment: acho que dessa forma funciona, porém e quando eu quiser mandar um array que não seja realizado uma consulta no BD, igual a questão anterior que vc me ajudou. Preciso de uma forma de poder enviar um lista que eu monto com slect no BD e tbm com input entende.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua colocação agora @HugoBorges. Se você pegar os emails do banco você pode fazer desta forma. Se você montar o array você pode fazer da outra forma.

Comment: Uma alternativa é padronizar a forma de objeto e transformar seu array se for necessário. **$object = (object) $array;**

Comment: hum entendi, bom testei aqui dessa forma e deu certo. Porém meu netbeans esta falando que a variável `$key` não esta sendo utilizada. Qual a necessidade dela?

Comment: Nesse caso só esta funcionando como contador mesmo(0,1,2,3 ...). Caso você fosse fazer alguma regra poderia usar. Você pode tirar se não for usar.

Comment: ok, muito obrigado :)